# If $a$ is divisible by $b$ is represented as $b\mid a$ then negation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, divisibility

How to write that $a$ is not divisible by $b$ using the bar? Is $a\nmid b$ correct?

(Note that the way to write these in LaTeX are

$a \mid b$ = `a \mid b`

and

$a \nmid b$ = `a \nmid b`.)

Comment: It would be $b \nmid a$: b does not divide a

Comment: Alright, thank you

Comment: You can use \not to put a slash on a symbol , meaning logical negation, e.g. a\not \in b, a\not |b, a\not\equiv b ...  $ a\not \in b,\;a\not |b, \;a\not\equiv b$.

Comment: In what I've seen the most common notation for "does not divide" has a short slash through the vertical line, as in @StephenDonovan's comment, but usually slightly higher up. The big slash, as in Daniel Wainfleet's comment is less common, but, as he notes, it results from the common TeX code \not.

Comment: The `b \nmid a` syntax is less widely known.

Comment: @InanimateBeing ...what? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was solved by (and thanks to) StephenDonovan, DanielWainfleet, AndreasBlass and user2661923. Since the question seemed unsolved on the outlook and a lot of time's passed so I'm just providing the compilation here.

1. Read $b\mid a$ (`b \mid a`) as "$b$ divides $a$" (not as "$a$ is divisible by $b$") to avoid any confusion.

   The symbol for "**$\bf b$ does not divide $\bf a$**" is: $\bf b\nmid a$ (`b \nmid a`).
2. Secondly, one can use `\not` to put a slash on a symbol, meaning logical negation.

   Egs: $a\not \in b$ (`a\not \in b`), $a\not |b$ (`a\not |b`), $a\not\equiv b$ (`a\not\equiv b`) $\dots$
3. The most common notation for "does not divide" has a short slash through the vertical line, as by `\nmid` (less widely known LaTeX notation), but usually slightly higher up. The big slash is less common but results from the common TeX code `\not`.